# Changing a graph by creating a new one

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, logic

Im making a graph that represents all the moves in a maze. Thing is when copying i repeated movements, so the output of my dictionary is as follow:

{(1, 2): [(2, 2)],

(3, 2): [(4, 2), (3, 3), (2, 2)],

(3, 3): [(3, 2), (3, 4)],

(5, 2): [(5, 3), (4, 2)],

(4, 4): [(5, 4), (3, 4)],

(5, 4): [(5, 3), (4, 4)],

(2, 2): [(3, 2), (1, 2)],

(4, 2): [(5, 2), (3, 2)],

(3, 4): [(4, 4), (3, 3)],

(5, 3): [(5, 2), (5, 4)]}

Any idea on how i can make a new dictionary based on old one and how to remove the repeated movements?

Edit: This dictionary is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it would be:

```
# Here's your node collection
toclean = {(1, 2): [(2, 2)],
(3, 2): [(4, 2), (3, 3), (2, 2)],
(3, 3): [(3, 2), (3, 4)],
(5, 2): [(5, 3), (4, 2)],
(4, 4): [(5, 4), (3, 4)],
(5, 4): [(5, 3), (4, 4)],
(2, 2): [(3, 2), (1, 2)],
(4, 2): [(5, 2), (3, 2)],
(3, 4): [(4, 4), (3, 3)],
(5, 3): [(5, 2), (5, 4)]}

# Here is a place to store nodes we've already seen
seen = set()

# Here is your new collection
result = {}

# Iterate over the original collection in sorted node order
for key, values in sorted(toclean.items()):
    # Mark node as seen
    seen.add(key)
    # Link it to any node that wasn't seen before
    result[key] = [val for val in values if val not in seen]

print result

{(1, 2): [(2, 2)],
 (2, 2): [(3, 2)],
 (3, 2): [(4, 2), (3, 3)],
 (3, 3): [(3, 4)],
 (3, 4): [(4, 4)],
 (4, 2): [(5, 2)],
 (4, 4): [(5, 4)],
 (5, 2): [(5, 3)],
 (5, 3): [(5, 4)],
 (5, 4): []}
```

But I'd like to see how you generate the graph: filtering there is better.